# nginx read response header when multiple headers have the same name

Tags: nginx

I want to read the following response headers.

Response-Header:

```
...
set-cookie: somecookie=7ABFBB3446C856779B59A837DE3946F7DB; Path=/; Secure;
set-cookie: wantedcookie=12414ASDFAFADFW2342342; Path=/; Secure;
...
```

The variable `$sent_http_set_cookie` contains the first header

`$sent_http_set_cookie = somecookie=7ABFBB3446C856779B59A837DE3946F7DB; Path=/; Secure;`

--

How to read the second header in order to get the value of the `wantedcookie`?

The nginx configuration looks like this:

```
location /api {
  add_header X-Debug "${sent_http_set_cookie}";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with you. I solved it by using the following code

```
local headers = ngx.resp.get_headers()
ngx.log(ngx.ERR, " set-cookie type is ", type(headers['set-cookie']))
ngx.log(ngx.ERR, "cookie headers are", require("cjson").encode(headers["set-cookie"]))
```

if there are multiple headers with the same, then `headers[name]` is a table.

ps: the code block show be placed in header_filter phase.

Comment: This is lua code as I see. Please state it in your answer.